# Materalize CSS error labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Materalize already supports validation for input fields such as email, but I would like to validate input fields such as passwords on the fly. Basically this means adding the error or success label through javacript.

My success so far has been poor. When I call the `change()` JS function and try to `addClass('valid')` for example, nothing happens and from what I can see, the class doesn't even appear in the HTML. I know the function is working because if I add a nonsense class like 'test', it does display in the HTML.

Is it not as simple as adding `'valid'` or `'invalid'` - do I need to meet other criteria before the label will appear?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to include the error labels as below:

```
            <div class="input-field col s9 offset-s1">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
            <input id="register_user" name ="register_user" type="text">
            <label id="reg-user-error" style="display:none" for="register_user" data-error="short" data-success="good">Username</label>
            <label for="register_user">Username</label>
        </div>
```

But making sure to hide the label by default. Then I only had to modify the classes with javascript and show the label. If you don't hide by default, any input automatically validates the label. My JS is:

```
$('#register_user').on('change',function()
```

{

```
if($('#register_user').val().length > 7)
{
    if($('#register_user').hasClass('invalid'))
    {
        $('#register_user').removeClass('invalid');
    }

    $('#register_user').addClass('valid');
    $('#reg-user-error').addClass('active');
    $('#reg-user-error').show();
}

else if($('#register_user').val().length < 8)
{
    if($('#register_user').hasClass('valid'))
    {
        $('#register_user').removeClass('valid');
    }

    $('#register_user').addClass('invalid');
    $('#reg-user-error').addClass('active');
    $('#reg-user-error').show();
}
```

});